# How to close an application window in Perl automation?

Tags: perl, windows-7, automation

I have an automation which opens many applications. I want to close all the opened windows at the end of the execution. I know I can use *SendKeys(%F4);* But I Don't want to use send keys function. Is there any other way closing an window.??

If any please let me know...

Thanks in advance... :)

Comment: "I Don't want to use send keys function." Why? By the way, which operating system are you using?

Comment: @leeduhem I am using windows7 and if i use send keys function I have to bring the window to foreground. As I am allowing user to perform other processes while the automation executes I don't want to disturb the foreground windows that may be present in foreground.

Comment: Oh, Windows... No idea how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22470407/how-to-close-an-application-window-in-perl-automation) which says **CloseWindow $HWND** Sends close signal to a window.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code.

```
MenuSelect("&Close", 0, GetSystemMenu(HWND, FALSE));
```

Which gets the default(System) menu which one can get by clicking the top left of the title bar, and makes the select operation on close.

Comment: THIS FUNCTION IS WORKING ONLY FOR WINDOWS IN FOREGROUND. I WANT TO PERFORM THE SAME OPERATION FOR ALL THE WINDOWS. BOTH FOREGROUND AND BACKGROUND.